# Как упростить конструкцию?

Tags: php

Каким образом можно упростить конструкцию, согласно всем канонам ООП и PSR

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class getInfo {
  private $ip;
  private $oid;
  private $community;

  public function __construct($ip, $community, $oid ){
    $this->ip = $ip;
    $this->community = $community;
    $this->oid = $oid;
  }

  public function snmpGet(){
    return snmp2_get($this->ip, $this->community, $this->oid);
  }
}

$snmp = new getInfo('10.12.1.2', 'public', 'iso.3.6.1.4.1.14988.1.1.17.1.1.4.1');
$snmp->snmpGet();
?>
```

Comment: Первична задача, не архитектура. Невозможно грамотно разработать архитектуру приложения, не зная требований к нему предъявляемых. Как минимум, нужно определить(иногда предсказать) необходимые оси свободы, векторы для расширения/изменений.

Comment: Если гадать, вы скорее всего захотите многократно получать данные для разных oid. Поэтому стоит перенести этот oid из конструктора в метод get.

Comment: вероятно такое подключение нужно только в единственном экземпляре, так что можно было бы подумать над тем чтобы `snmpGet()` сохранял подключение в статическом поле объекта и при повторном вызове вытаскивал оттуда, а не подключался снова

Answer (score 3):

Так как данный класс не предоставляет никакой дополнительной функциональности, при прочих равных можно упростить этот код вот так:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
snmp2_get('10.12.1.2', 'public', 'iso.3.6.1.4.1.14988.1.1.17.1.1.4.1');
```

Если ответить на вопрос зачем нужен этот класс, можно придумать что-нибудь иное.

Некоторые идеи могут возникнуть, если вспомнить, что уже существует нативный класс, представляющий SNMP сессию: [SNMP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.snmp.php)

```
$session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2C, '10.12.1.2', 'public');
$info = $session->get('iso.3.6.1.4.1.14988.1.1.17.1.1.4.1');
```

С подобным(или с этим) интерфейсом вы можете писать/читать данные, не передавая общие данные сессии(host, community) каждый раз

Comment: почему при "нативном классе" время от времени появляется INTEGER: или STRING: Бывает есть, обновляешь страницу и пропадает. Потом появляется при следующем обновлении страницы. Как убрать её насовсем? Вывожу не var_dump`ом